# What exact code is needed for Wordpress/Woocommerce login/sign up pages

Tags: authentication, wordpress, woocommerce, forgot-password

I am creating a small e-commerce website using wordpress & woocommerce but I'm not really understanding the login/signup abilities for users. I just want users who visit the site to be able to click a link on the home page where they can sign up and login (with the option to reset their passwords) and in return those customer details are saved within the user data for the wordpress admin to be able to see. What is the coding for this? Because I can't seem to get into a lot of these plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
  global $wpdb, $user_ID; 
    $firstname='';
    $lastname='';
    $username='';
    $email='';

    //if looged in rediret to home page
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        wp_redirect( get_option('home') );// redirect to home page
        exit;
    }

    if(sanitize_text_field( $_POST['com_submit']) != ''){

        $firstname=sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['com_firstname'] );
        $lastname=sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['com_lastname']);
        $username = sanitize_text_field(  $_REQUEST['com_username'] );
        $email = sanitize_text_field(  $_REQUEST['com_email']  );
        $password = $wpdb->escape( sanitize_text_field(    $_REQUEST['com_password']));
        $status = wp_create_user($username,$password,$email);

        if (is_wp_error($status))  {
             $error_msg = __('Username or Email already registered. Please try another one.','twentyten'); 
        } 
        else{
            $user_id=$status;
            update_user_meta( $user_id,'first_name', $firstname);
            update_user_meta( $user_id,'last_name', $lastname);


            //code to auto login start
            $alar_enable_auto_login= get_option('alar_enable_auto_login');

            if($alar_enable_auto_login==''){
             $alar_enable_auto_login= 'true';
            }

            if($alar_enable_auto_login == 'true'){
                if(!is_user_logged_in()){
                    $secure_cookie = is_ssl();
                    $secure_cookie = apply_filters('secure_signon_cookie', $secure_cookie, array());
                    global $auth_secure_cookie;
                    $auth_secure_cookie = $secure_cookie;
                    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, true, $secure_cookie);
                    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
                    do_action('wp_login', $user_info->user_login, $user_info);
                }
            }
            //code to auto login end

            wp_redirect( get_option('home') );// redirect to home page
            exit;
        }  
    }
?>
    <div class="alar-registration-form">
        <div class="alar-registration-heading">
        <?php _e("Registration Form",'');?>
        </div>
        <?php if($error_msg!='') { ?><div class="error"><?php echo $error_msg; ?></div><?php }  ?>
        <form  name="form" id="registration"  method="post">
            <div class="ftxt">
             <label><?php _e("First Name :",'');?></label> 
             <input id="com_firstname" name="com_firstname" type="text" class="input" required value=<?php echo $firstname; ?> > 
            </div>
            <div class="ftxt">
             <label><?php _e("Last name :",'');?></label>  
             <input id="com_lastname" name="com_lastname" type="text" class="input" required value=<?php echo $lastname; ?> >
            </div>
            <div class="ftxt">
             <label><?php _e("Username :",'');?></label> 
             <input id="com_username" name="com_username" type="text" class="input" required value=<?php echo $username; ?> >
            </div>
            <div class="ftxt">
            <label><?php _e("E-mail :",'');?> </label>
             <input id="com_email" name="com_email" type="email" class="input" required value=<?php echo $email; ?> >
            </div>
            <div class="ftxt">
            <label><?php _e("Password :",'');?></label>
             <input id="password1" name="com_password" type="password" required class="input" />
            </div>
            <div class="ftxt">
            <label><?php _e("Confirm Password : ",'');?></label>
             <input id="password2" name="c_password" type="password" class="input" />
            </div>
            <div class="fbtn"><input type="submit" name='com_submit' class="button"  value="Register"/> </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php   
}

//add registration shortcoode
add_shortcode( 'registration-form', 'alar_registration_shortcode' );


// function to login Shortcode
function alar_login_shortcode( $atts ) {

   //if looged in rediret to home page
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        wp_redirect( get_option('home') );// redirect to home page
        exit;
    }

    global $wpdb; 
    if(sanitize_text_field( $_GET['login'] ) != ''){
     $login_fail_msg=sanitize_text_field( $_GET['login'] );
    }
    ?>
    <div class="alar-login-form">
    <?php if($login_fail_msg=='failed'){?>
    <div class="error"  align="center"><?php _e('Username or password is incorrect','');?></div>
    <?php }?>
        <div class="alar-login-heading">
        <?php _e("Login Form",'');?>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo get_option('home');?>/wp-login.php" id="loginform" name="loginform" >
            <div class="ftxt">
            <label><?php _e('Login ID :','');?> </label>
             <input type="text" tabindex="10" size="20" value="" class="input" id="user_login" required name="log" />
            </div>
            <div class="ftxt">
            <label><?php _e('Password :','');?> </label>
              <input type="password" tabindex="20" size="20" value="" class="input" id="user_pass" required name="pwd" />
            </div>
            <div class="fbtn">
            <input type="submit" tabindex="100" value="Log In" class="button" id="wp-submit" name="wp-submit" />
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_option('home');?>" name="redirect_to">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>



just copy and past This code where do  you want to add register login form
```

Comment: Does this go in the index.php or functions.php?

Comment: on your page ont in function.php